# Automatic triger not executing, manually executing works perfectly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My script works perfectly when I execute it manually through the editor but fails to fire with the edit or change trigger.

I saw a bunch of people having the same problem but none of these solutions help me solving this issue.

Has anybody a solution for this ?

```
function createNewSheets() {
  // 1. Retrieve the current sheet names.
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = dataSheet.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName());

  // 2. Retrieve the values from "mastersheet" sheet.
  var masterSheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName('Liste de nageurs');
  var values = masterSheet.getRange('A2:B' + masterSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 3. Using the retrieved sheet names and values, the new sheets are inserted and the values are put.
  values.forEach(r => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(r[0])) {
      var newSheet = dataSheet.insertSheet(r[0])
      sheetNames.push(r[0]);
      newSheet.appendRow(r);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Try using an installable trigger.

Comment: Since I'm a beginner.. How ? Haha :)

Comment: Never mind.  It's not necessary.  See example below.

Answer (score 2):

I ran it this way, using a checkbox in A1:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');//just a toast to let me know it's work
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();// getting sheet name 
  //next line limits execution to Sheet1 A1 being changed to 'TRUE'
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');//reset the checkbox back to 'FALSE'
    //the rest is your code
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var names = ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName());
    var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//changed sheet name
    var vs = masterSheet.getRange('A2:B' + masterSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    vs.forEach(r => {
      if (!names.includes(r[0])) {
        var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(r[0])
        names.push(r[0]);
        newSheet.appendRow(r);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can simplify your code if you learn how to use the event object better but I left most of your code intact.  The problem that most users dislike about using the event object is that you can't debug the code by running it from the script editor because you have to supply the event object as a parameter.  I normally debug them but running them from the trigger.  You can use JSON.stringify(e) to look at the event object.

Using the event object normally results in faster code and simple triggers must finish in 30 seconds or less.

Comment: It's certainly better code than what I did. But it doesn't work on my side and most of all, I don't understand it. Even if it would be easier for me to ask someone to do it for me, I'd like to understand every single line and how it works / what it does.

Comment: You cannot run it from the script editor any longer because I'm using the event object to limit the range that it runs from.  You will need to change the sheet names and add the check box

Comment: Typically I don't provide comments because I think that's your responsibility to dig into the documentation and figure it out yourself.  The most important part of that process is giving you experience dealing with the documentation which I personally refer to all of the time when writing code.  It's an indispensable tool for me.  It's not possible to remember everything in the documenation and that's especially true for online documentation which is constantly changing.

Comment: Ok now I better understand what you did and how it works ! Thanks for helping further than usual. One question remains : why unchecking the box ? Because when I have a new entry in the sheet, it doesn't check automatically again. So it needs manual action to work, right ?

Comment: You can do what you want for your user interface. I unchecked it because I want it to be ready for next time.  Essentially I'm using the checkbox as a button.

Comment: Ok so I may not be right, but it's not a solution for my goal to automate everything. My point here is that I need a new sheet to be created automatically when a new row is added in the mastersheet. So here we're at the same place than in the beginning. I need to manually execute the script. Don't be mad, I may not get it at all.

Comment: I'm not mad.  How you wish to design something isn't what we're here for.  We answer programming questions.  The problem with adding a line to a sheet is that with onedit the trigger doesn't know when your through typing.  So you need some kind of defiinitive user action.  And in  the case of simple triggers it must be a user action not a script or formula action.  So in my mind a checkbox is perfect.